# Android to Objective-c translate

Tags: java, objective-c

I am working on some project have a problem that ios app doesn't play video when opened the page. So I found some source code that didn't have in StandartPlug.m
but issue is that I can not add those codes in Obj-c language from java. Please help me translation.

```
else if(mServiceId.equals("movFilePlay"))  {    //hband 이상연대표 요청 220415

                String filePath = mParamData.getString( "filePath" );

                Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
                intent.setData( Uri.parse( filePath ) );
                startActivity( intent );
                break;
```

I need to translate to Objective-c language ro add required places
[I tried to translate it but couldn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAYyX.jpg)

Comment: You wrote `NSDate` instead of `NSData` (for the unknown method warning). Twice btw, one in "ImageView" if, and the other in "MovFilePlay" if. `NSDate` != `NSData`.

Comment: @Larme I just wanted to translate those codes to put the place. I don't understand java language and have no idea what's going on in there.

Comment: The problem is I need to call video file from server and play it on app side.